Where can I find providers and aliases in Laravel 11?
In Laravel 11, I noticed that the config/app.php file no longer contains the providers and aliases arrays as it did in previous versions.
Where can I find the providers and aliases in Laravel 11, or how are they registered and managed in this version?
I searched for documentation on service providers and aliases in Laravel 11 but couldn't find clear guidance. I expected to see them in config/app.php as before, but they're missing. I'm unsure how to set them up now and couldn't find updated instructions.
Any help would be appreciated!

This question is similar to: How to publish service provider to the application in laravel 11. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks for the suggestion. The linked question only covers service providers. My question is about both service providers and class aliases. I need help with how class aliases are handled in Laravel 11.

Go in the App\Providers; add the use Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader;  on the Head and create the
    $this->app->register(\Milon\Barcode\BarcodeServiceProvider::class);

        
        $loader = AliasLoader::getInstance();
        $loader->alias('DNS1D', \Milon\Barcode\Facades\DNS1DFacade::class);
        $loader->alias('DNS2D', \Milon\Barcode\Facades\DNS2DFacade::class);
}

NOW your providers and aliases are ready.
The full file will look like something this:
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader;



class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
       // Register Milon Barcode provider
       $this->app->register(\Milon\Barcode\BarcodeServiceProvider::class);

       // Register the alias dynamically
       $loader = AliasLoader::getInstance();
       $loader->alias('DNS1D', \Milon\Barcode\Facades\DNS1DFacade::class);
       $loader->alias('DNS2D', \Milon\Barcode\Facades\DNS2DFacade::class);
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        //
    }
}


provider in laravel 11 change to directory bootstrap/providers.php
